# Interface and alias up at the same time

Tags: networking, centos, networkcard

I have on my `eth0` NIC card the following IP alias (I'm running CentOS 6.2):

`eth0` - IP: 192.168.50.1

`eth0:5` - IP: 10.0.0.1

Now, when I boot the server, both interfaces come up and respond, but if I try to run: `ifup eth0` or `ifup eth0:5`, it no longer permits me to keep them both up. Only the interface declared in the command will be up. The other will be disconnected.

Can anybody explain me why that happens, and how to bring up both interfaces when I need to reset one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by disabling `NetworkManager` service. Probably, if you need that service to be active, you can take in account the Tim's suggestion, or you can make use of `NM_CONTROLLED=no` option. Anyway, with this option used, I think you will need to do some other settings.

Answer (score 1):

Does `ONPARENT=yes` declaration exist in your alias configuration file? That directive will bring "up" the alias when the parent is brought "up".